# Google Tango - Using 3D Reconstruction

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, 3d-reconstruction

I’m currently working with Google Tango and I’m trying to get an example scene to run on Unity. The scene is called „ExperimentalMeshBuilderWithColor“ and can be found in the folder Assets>TangoSDK>Examples>Scenes after importing the Tango SDK to Unity.

So far, the app always crashes at the same location in the code but not consistent, meaning that the app runs for a seeming random amount of time and then stops working. The only reproducible observation is the location in the code itself, but not the time it takes to crash (which varies from 10 seconds to 5 minutes runtime). 
The location is in the function of `API.Tango3DR_extractPreallocatedMeshSegment(m_context, ref gridIndex, ref mesh);` which is called in the script „Tango3DReconstrucion.cs“ (Assets>TangoSDK>Core>Scripts>TangoWrappers).

It seems to me that the crash occurs within the „tango_3d_reconstruction.so“ library (Assets>Plugins>Android>libs>armeabi-v7a) which is imported using `[DllImport(TANGO_3DR_DLL)]` and `private const string TANGO_3DR_DLL = „tango_3d_reconstruction“;` in the aforementioned script „Tango3DReconstrucion.cs“. As this library is not open-source, I cannot search further than I have up to now. 
I’m adding the crash dump file logged with logcats adb and hope somebody has had similar problems and can suggest a way to solve the problem.

Other things I’ve tried so far without success:
- Disabled „Draw Default Ux Exceptions“ in Tango Ux Script
- Disabled „Dynamic Batching“ in Player Settings
- Enabled „Selective Meshing“ in Tango Dynamic Mesh Script
- Varying "Resolution", "Mesh Min Vertices" and "Point Cloud Max Points" in Tango Manager
- Enabled „Allow out of Date API“ in Tango Manager

```
I/Unity   (18880): API Tango 3DR extraction of mesh segment
I/Unity   (18880): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)
F/tango   (18880): mesh-toolbox.cc:652 'faces_in' Must be non NULL
F/libc    (18880): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000049c0 (code=-6), thread 18901 (UnityMain)
W/st-log  (16075): Initial features: Max - 7749, Min - 8877
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): FlashError: Flash Parameter Error!!
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): FlashError: TorchBrightness is 0!!
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): FlashError: Torch on midtone common gain is 0!!
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): FlashError: Torch on highlight common gain is 0!!
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): FlashError: Torch on luma is 0!!
I/DEBUG   (  161): ***
I/DEBUG   (  161): Build fingerprint: 'google/tango/yellowstone:4.4.2/KOT49H.160920/160920002:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  161): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (  161): pid: 18880, tid: 18901, name: UnityMain  >>> com.ICVR.Hirtc <<<
I/DEBUG   (  161): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
W/st-log  (16075): Final features: 12445
W/st-log  (16075): Initial features: Max - 7748, Min - 8872
I/DEBUG   (  161):     r0 00000000  r1 000049d5  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  161):     r4 00000006  r5 00000000  r6 000049d5  r7 0000010c
I/DEBUG   (  161):     r8 4fc0ee9c  r9 493b2bd8  sl 493b2a74  fp 493b2a78
I/DEBUG   (  161):     ip 4fc0da30  sp 493b25e8  lr 40045011  pc 40053f78  cpsr 000f0010
I/DEBUG   (  161):     d0  6e20656220747375  d1  0a4c4c554e206e6f
I/DEBUG   (  161):     d2  6361662720323536  d3  4d20276e695f7365
I/DEBUG   (  161):     d4  bfa1999900000000  d5  3f800000be59999b
I/DEBUG   (  161):     d6  7fc000007fc00000  d7  7fc0000000000004
I/DEBUG   (  161):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  000000004479999a
I/DEBUG   (  161):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  161):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  161):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  161):     d16 0000000000000000  d17 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  161):     d18 404ec923fbf77686  d19 0000000000004400
I/DEBUG   (  161):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 3f3280f6be826169
I/DEBUG   (  161):     d22 8000000080000000  d23 0000000080000000
I/DEBUG   (  161):     d24 3f3280f600000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  161):     d26 8000000080000000  d27 3f8000003f800000
I/DEBUG   (  161):     d28 00000000be826169  d29 8000000080000000
I/DEBUG   (  161):     d30 3f3280f6be826169  d31 beba7ea2bf0ff884
I/DEBUG   (  161):     scr 3000009b
I/DEBUG   (  161): 
I/DEBUG   (  161): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  161):     #00  pc 00021f78  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
I/DEBUG   (  161):     #01  pc 0001300d  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
I/DEBUG   (  161):     #02  pc 00013221  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
I/DEBUG   (  161):     #03  pc 00011f57  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  161):     #04  pc 0002182c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG   (  161):     #05  pc 0000684b  /system/lib/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+86)
I/DEBUG   (  161):     #06  pc 0005e69d  /data/app-lib/com.ICVR.Hirtc-2/libtango_3d_reconstruction.so
I/DEBUG   (  161): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25a8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25ac  4479999a  /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so (android::JMediaCodec::JMediaCodec(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, char const*, bool, bool)+177)
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25b0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25b4  000003ff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25b8  4fc5e484  
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25bc  4fc0ee60  /data/app-lib/com.ICVR.Hirtc-2/libtango_3d_reconstruction.so
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25c0  4fc0da30  /data/app-lib/com.ICVR.Hirtc-2/libtango_3d_reconstruction.so
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25c4  4fc0ee9c  /data/app-lib/com.ICVR.Hirtc-2/libtango_3d_reconstruction.so
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25c8  493b2bd8  [stack:18901]
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25cc  493b2a74  [stack:18901]
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25d0  40028439  /system/lib/libcutils.so
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25d4  5579c454  [anon:libc_malloc]
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25d8  493b264c  [stack:18901]
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25dc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25e0  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25e4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     #00  493b25e8  00000006  
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25ec  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25f0  000049d5  
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25f4  4fc0da30  /data/app-lib/com.ICVR.Hirtc-2/libtango_3d_reconstruction.so
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25f8  4fc0da30  /data/app-lib/com.ICVR.Hirtc-2/libtango_3d_reconstruction.so
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b25fc  40045011  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
I/DEBUG   (  161):     #01  493b2600  00000006  
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b2604  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b2608  4fc0ee60  /data/app-lib/com.ICVR.Hirtc-2/libtango_3d_reconstruction.so
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b260c  40045225  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+14)
I/DEBUG   (  161):     #02  493b2610  493b261c  [stack:18901]
I/DEBUG   (  161):          493b2614  40043f5b  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  161): 
I/DEBUG   (  161): memory near r1:
I/DEBUG   (  161):     000049b4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     000049c4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     000049d4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     000049e4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     000049f4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a04 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a14 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a24 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a34 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a44 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a54 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a64 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a74 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a84 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a94 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004aa4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161): 
I/DEBUG   (  161): memory near r6:
I/DEBUG   (  161):     000049b4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     000049c4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     000049d4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     000049e4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     000049f4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a04 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a14 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a24 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a34 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a44 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a54 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a64 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a74 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a84 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004a94 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     00004aa4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161): 
I/DEBUG   (  161): memory near r8:
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0ee7c 5495de30 5495e028 5002c6ac 5495de48  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0ee8c 5495de30 5495e028 5002c6ac 00000100  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0ee9c 00000001 4b25f014 4b26562c 4b26a334  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0eeac 4b263634 4b26833c 4b266344 4b25f644  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0eebc 00000000 4b26163c 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0eecc 4b25c2c4 4b2ff014 4b27094c 4b25c248  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0eedc 4b25c27c 4b25c27c 4edf8014 4b25c280  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0eeec 4b25c2b4 4b25c2b4 4b26e954 4edfa00c  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0eefc 4b26c32c 4b26c95c 4edfc004 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0ef0c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0ef1c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0ef2c 3ff00000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0ef3c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0ef4c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0ef5c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0ef6c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161): 
I/DEBUG   (  161): memory near r9:
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2bb8 00000000 00000000 56902894 567ddfac  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2bc8 0000028c 5579c454 4fc0992c 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2bd8 4fc09940 4fc097d0 56067b94 56067b94  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2be8 56067b95 56067b94 56067bc4 56067d94  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2bf8 4fc5d620 00000018 56067b94 4fc09954  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2c08 00000006 00000000 00001002 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2c18 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2c28 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2c38 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2c48 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2c58 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2c68 00000008 493b2c28 4fc5d620 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2c78 00000120 493b2bdc 4fc5d908 4fc5dcc4  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2c88 4fc5e3b8 fffffffd 400801c0 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2c98 00000000 00000000 00000000 493b2fb0  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2ca8 493b3410 fffff020 493b3360 4f53a14d  
I/DEBUG   (  161): 
I/DEBUG   (  161): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2a54 4f4f86a1 4fb07064 567fdfec 56067ba8  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2a64 493b2a80 493b2a88 493b2a8c 493b2fb0  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2a74 4fc5e490 56902894 0000028c 5579c454  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2a84 fffffffd 567fdfec 567ddfac 561b2a9c  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2a94 5684bca0 493b2bc0 493b2fb0 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2aa4 493b2fb0 493b3410 493b2b38 493b3360  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2ab4 4f539f5d fffffffd ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2ac4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2ad4 ffffffff 4fc0da30 ffffffff 55dd1d30  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2ae4 00000000 493b2bc0 493b2b28 ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2af4 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2b04 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2b14 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2b24 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2b34 ffffffff 561b2a9c ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2b44 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161): 
I/DEBUG   (  161): memory near fp:
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2a58 4fb07064 567fdfec 56067ba8 493b2a80  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2a68 493b2a88 493b2a8c 493b2fb0 4fc5e490  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2a78 56902894 0000028c 5579c454 fffffffd  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2a88 567fdfec 567ddfac 561b2a9c 5684bca0  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2a98 493b2bc0 493b2fb0 00000000 493b2fb0  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2aa8 493b3410 493b2b38 493b3360 4f539f5d  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2ab8 fffffffd ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2ac8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2ad8 4fc0da30 ffffffff 55dd1d30 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2ae8 493b2bc0 493b2b28 ffffffff 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2af8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2b08 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2b18 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2b28 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2b38 561b2a9c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2b48 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161): 
I/DEBUG   (  161): memory near ip:
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0da10 4fc0a1e0 4fa88ccc 4fc0a2a0 4fc0a2c8  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0da20 4fc0a2b8 4fa8a5ec 4fbcc9f8 4fbcca94  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0da30 00000000 00000000 00000000 4005ae85  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0da40 4005af81 4003fc45 4003fc31 40040820  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0da50 40040924 40028739 400579f9 40050b55  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0da60 40040f78 40040d90 40044f55 40040ca8  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0da70 40040d6c 40055a9c 40040600 40040d2c  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0da80 4003f258 400287f5 4005453c 40053b58  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0da90 40055091 40061da1 4b2fb9d9 40053fb8  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0daa0 4b2fba9d 400a56a4 40094514 40094504  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0dab0 4033e8dc 4033e060 4033e24c 4033e328  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0dac0 4033e154 4033e2c4 4033e3dc 4033e364  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0dad0 4033e314 4033e140 4033e04c 4033e378  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0dae0 4033eb20 4033e4d0 4033e074 4033e788  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0daf0 4033e3b4 4033e088 4033e864 4033e8a0  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     4fc0db00 4033e3c8 4033e128 4033e418 4033e42c  
I/DEBUG   (  161): 
I/DEBUG   (  161): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b25c8 493b2bd8 493b2a74 40028439 5579c454  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b25d8 493b264c 00000000 df0027ad 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b25e8 00000006 00000000 000049d5 4fc0da30  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b25f8 4fc0da30 40045011 00000006 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2608 4fc0ee60 40045225 493b261c 40043f5b  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2618 ffffffff ffffffdf ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2628 ffffffff a717134c ffffffff 5579c454  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2638 4fc5e484 40053830 40028439 4002884f  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2648 493b2a5c 6873656d 6f6f742d 786f626c  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2658 3a63632e 20323536 63616627 695f7365  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2668 4d20276e 20747375 6e206562 4e206e6f  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2678 0a4c4c55 ffffff00 ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2688 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b2698 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b26a8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     493b26b8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  161): 
I/DEBUG   (  161): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40053f58 e8bd00f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40053f68 ea006f7c e92d50f0 e3a07f43 ef000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40053f78 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40053f88 ea006f74 e92d50f0 e3a070ee ef000000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40053f98 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40053fa8 ea006f6c 00000000 e1520003 8a0000ab  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40053fb8 f5d1f040 e92d4001 e3520000 11500001  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40053fc8 08bd8001 f5d1f000 f5d1f040 e3520020  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40053fd8 3a00008f e3520080 3a000084 e2603000  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40053fe8 e213303f 0a000015 e0422003 e1b0cf83  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40053ff8 44d1c001 44c0c001 24d1c001 24c0c001  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40054008 24d1c001 24c0c001 e1b0ce83 5a000001  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40054018 f4a1030d f480031d 3a000001 f421070d  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40054028 f400071d e1b0cd83 5a000001 f4210a0d  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40054038 f4000a2d 3a000001 f421020d f400023d  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40054048 f5d1f080 f5d1f0c0 e3520902 3a000004  
I/DEBUG   (  161): 
I/DEBUG   (  161): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40044ff0 447b4b13 42b3e010 4812d10e 44786a1e  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40045000 ec90f7fb e9d8f00d 46224631 efaef00e  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40045010 d00a3001 e00b2400 2b00681b 480ad1eb  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40045020 44782403 ec7ef7fb f001e002 6804fa1b  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40045030 fa18f001 46206005 bf00bd70 0003b3b2  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40045040 0003b3a6 0003b39e 0003b37a bf7ef7ff  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40045050 4a3e4b3d 43f0e92d 4606b08b 447b460d  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40045060 6823589c 930946a1 f9fcf001 8000f8d0  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40045070 d0482d00 f0104628 280ff80b d8444604  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40045080 ffe4f7ff d1064286 4629200f e8a2f00d  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     40045090 d03c2800 482ee02e f7fb4478 482debc2  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     400450a0 e0154478 d11342b0 482b6a06 f7fb4478  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     400450b0 4a2aec3a 46332120 447aa801 fc24f013  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     400450c0 a8012101 ff22f01a 46061c42 e011d104  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     400450d0 28006800 e02cd1e6 46294630 f00d4622  
I/DEBUG   (  161):     400450e0 1c43e8de d11e4607 f9bcf001 29046801  
W/st-log  (16075): Final features: 12670
W/st-log  (16075): Initial features: Max - 7811, Min - 8820
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): FlashError: Flash Parameter Error!!
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): FlashError: TorchBrightness is 0!!
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): FlashError: Torch on midtone common gain is 0!!
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): FlashError: Torch on highlight common gain is 0!!
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): FlashError: Torch on luma is 0!!
W/st-log  (16075): Final features: 13076
I/BootReceiver(  899): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_04 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
W/ActivityManager(  899):   Force finishing activity com.ICVR.Hirtc/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity
W/st-log  (16075): Initial features: Max - 8554, Min - 9290
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): FlashError: Flash Parameter Error!!
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): FlashError: TorchBrightness is 0!!
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): FlashError: Torch on midtone common gain is 0!!
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): FlashError: Torch on highlight common gain is 0!!
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): FlashError: Torch on luma is 0!!
W/InputDispatcher(  899): channel '65134b70 com.ICVR.Hirtc/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
E/InputDispatcher(  899): channel '65134b70 com.ICVR.Hirtc/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
W/InputDispatcher(  899): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '65134b70 com.ICVR.Hirtc/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity (server)'
I/WindowState(  899): WIN DEATH: Window{65134b70 u0 com.ICVR.Hirtc/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity}
W/MediaFocusControl(  899):   AudioFocus   audio focus client died
I/MediaFocusControl(  899): AudioFocus  removeFocusStackEntry(): removing entry for android.os.BinderProxy@64d37158
E/Sensors (  899): [nosae] setDelay: 8000000 sec
D/Sensors (  899): Writing packet 54 32 0A 04 40 1F 00 00 74 
I/tango   (16075): TangoService.cc:176 ThreadLoop attempting disconnect number 1.
I/tango   (16075): tango_context.cc:617 TangoContext::StopRuntime() /data/data/com.google.tango/files/datasets/
I/tango   (16075): tango_application.cc:310 TangoApplication: Stopping...
I/tango   (16075): tango_hal_device_wrapper.cc:187 HAL device wrapper calling stop.
W/tango   (16075): tango_image_callback.cc:48 Could not promote most recent yuv image.
W/tango   (16075): tango_image_callback.cc:48 Could not promote most recent yuv image.
I/WindowState(  899): WIN DEATH: Window{6514a170 u0 SurfaceView}
D/Sensors (  899): Writing packet 54 36 0B 00 74 
D/phs:ipc-loc(  180): Socket 11: hangup from client "com.ICVR.Hirtc"
W/ActivityManager(  899): Exception thrown during pause
W/ActivityManager(  899): android.os.DeadObjectException
W/ActivityManager(  899):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  899):   at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:660)
W/ActivityManager(  899):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:768)
W/ActivityManager(  899):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2473)
W/ActivityManager(  899):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2347)
W/ActivityManager(  899):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2045)
W/ActivityManager(  899):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:9569)
W/ActivityManager(  899):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:9462)
W/ActivityManager(  899):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:10107)
W/ActivityManager(  899):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:9658)
W/ActivityManager(  899):   at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
D/Sensors (  899): Writing packet 54 31 0B 00 74 
E/Sensors (  899): [nosae] setDelay: 10000000 sec
D/Sensors (  899): Writing packet 54 32 0A 04 10 27 00 00 74 
I/ActivityManager(  899): Process com.ICVR.Hirtc (pid 18880) has died.
D/Sensors (  899): Writing packet 54 36 10 00 74 
D/Sensors (  899): Writing packet 54 31 10 00 74 
I/art     (  899): Heap trim of managed (duration=15.580083ms, advised=2000KB) and native (duration=3.711084ms, advised=1388KB) heaps. Managed heap utilization of 67%.
W/st-log  (16075): Final features: 15209
I/ActivityManager(  899): Killing 14992:com.google.android.youtube/u0a70 (adj 15): empty #17
I/art     (  165): Process 18880 terminated by signal (6)
I/art     ( 1218): GcCauseBackground sticky partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10044(598KB) AllocSpace objects, 22(599KB) LOS objects, 5% free, 16MB/17MB, paused 5.245ms total 30.962ms
I/CastMediaRouteProvider(10905): in onDiscoveryRequestChanged: request=null
W/MdnsClient_Cast(10905): Multicast lock held. Releasing. Subtypes:"233637DE"
W/MdnsClient(10905): unicast receiver thread is already dead.
W/GCoreFlp(11146): No location to return for getLastLocation()
W/FusedLocationProvider(11146): location=null
W/GCoreFlp(11146): No location to return for getLastLocation()
W/FusedLocationProvider(11146): location=null
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): routeResultFromCAM: WARNING: only 0 requests in flight on sensor 0, frame drops likely
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): routeResultFromCAM: WARNING: only 0 requests in flight on sensor 1, frame drops likely
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): NvCamScaler_OutputThread-- (error 0x0)
I/art     ( 1218): GcCauseBackground partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8107(513KB) AllocSpace objects, 18(3MB) LOS objects, 6% free, 13MB/14MB, paused 7.073ms total 27.552ms
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): SensorBayer_SetPowerLevel 1
E/Sensors (  899): [nosae] setDelay: 10000000 sec
D/Sensors (  899): Writing packet 54 32 0A 04 10 27 00 00 74 
I/Camera2ClientBase(  171): Closed Camera 1
I/tango   (16075): tango_hal_device_wrapper.cc:190 HAL device wrapper stop call succeeded.
I/tango   (16075): image-cache-inl.h:356 Starting ImageCache drain.
I/tango   (16075): image-cache-inl.h:385 Finished ImageCache drain.
I/tango   (16075): image-cache-inl.h:356 Starting ImageCache drain.
I/tango   (16075): image-cache-inl.h:385 Finished ImageCache drain.
I/tango   (16075): tango_application.cc:347 TangoApplication: Joined successfully.
I/tango   (16075): TangoService.cc:182 ThreadLoop stopped Tango Runtime.
I/tango   (16075): tango_context.cc:637 TangoContext::DestroyRuntime()
I/tango   (16075): tango_context.cc:1755 TangoContext: Destroying Tango Service Application.
I/tango   (16075): tango_context.cc:1599 Logging 2 events.
I/tango   (16075): tango_application.cc:310 TangoApplication: Stopping...
I/tango   (16075): image-cache-inl.h:356 Starting ImageCache drain.
I/tango   (16075): image-cache-inl.h:385 Finished ImageCache drain.
I/tango   (16075): image-cache-inl.h:356 Starting ImageCache drain.
I/tango   (16075): image-cache-inl.h:385 Finished ImageCache drain.
I/tango   (16075): tango_application.cc:347 TangoApplication: Joined successfully.
I/tango   (16075): tango_context.cc:1764 Trying to reset application_.
I/tango   (16075): image-cache-inl.h:356 Starting ImageCache drain.
I/tango   (16075): image-cache-inl.h:385 Finished ImageCache drain.
I/tango   (16075): image-cache-inl.h:356 Starting ImageCache drain.
I/tango   (16075): image-cache-inl.h:385 Finished ImageCache drain.
I/tango   (16075): tango-hal-interface.cc:96 Average feature detection frequency: 10.0257
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): NvCamScaler_OutputThread-- (error 0x0)
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  171): SensorBayer_SetPowerLevel 1
D/Sensors (  899): Writing packet 54 36 0A 00 74 
D/Sensors (  899): Writing packet 54 31 0A 00 74 
I/tango   (16075): tango_hal_wrapper.cc:112 Closing Tango HAL.
I/tango   (16075): tango_hal_device_wrapper.cc:216 HAL device wrapper calling close, buffer balance at: 0
I/tango   (16075): tango_hal_device_wrapper.cc:224 HAL device wrapper close call succeeded.
I/tango   (16075): feature_tracker.cc:49 Total num. of frame-frame matches before RANSAC: 301924
I/tango   (16075): manager.cc:131 IMU average latency 0.52253ms variance 0.498342 max 9.95973ms hz 100.067
I/tango   (16075): manager.cc:137 VIO average latency 17.8815ms variance 49.9061 max 51.4582ms hz 10.0159
I/tango   (16075): tango_context.cc:1767 Done resetting application_. (Took 0.710731 seconds.)
I/tango   (16075): tango_context.cc:1599 Logging 4 events.
I/Camera2ClientBase(  171): Closed Camera 0
I/tango   (16075): tango_context.cc:1772 TangoContext: Runtime has shut down! (Took 0.713128 seconds.)
I/tango   (16075): TangoService.cc:187 ThreadLoop destroyed Tango Runtime.
I/art     ( 1700): Heap trim of managed (duration=1.129500ms, advised=104KB) and native (duration=578.166us, advised=0B) heaps. Managed heap utilization of 56%.
E/WifiController(  899): Not handled here 155652
D/WifiController(  899): battery changed pluggedType: 2
I/DownloadManagerWrapper( 1143): onReceive() : Charging = false
I/PlayCommon(17218): [831] PlayEventLogger.uploadEventsImpl: Preparing logs for uploading
I/PlayCommon(17218): [831] PlayEventLogger.uploadEventsImpl: No file ready to send
```